# Using PHP to get exit value from a shell script

Tags: php, shell

I have a shell script that exits a number (0 for success and 1 for failure). Using PHP, I need to get this number, 0 or 1, and use it in an if statement.
For example:

```
if (VALUE1or0 == 0)
    echo "success";
else 
    echo "failure";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get result of shell script like this:

```
$cmd = "./run 2>&1";
$ret = shell_exec($cmd);
var_dump($ret);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)

```
 $output = shell_exec('your script');
    if($output == 0){
        echo 'success';
    }else{
        echo 'failure';
    }
```

Comment: when I use this code, the output is always success.

Answer (score 0):

[PHP: exec - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

> `string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )`
>   …
>      If the `return_var` argument is present    along with
>   the `output` argument, then the    return status of the
>   executed command will be written to this    variable.

```
exec('/bin/false', $output, $VALUE1or0);
if ($VALUE1or0 == 0)
    echo "success\n";
else 
    echo "failure\n";
```